# JavaScript ES6 parse nested delimited strings to key/values

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, string, object

I have the following array of objects:

```
var addresses = [ 
  { ResourceId: 2,
    OfficeAddress:
     '20 Main Street\r\nRiverside\r\nUSA' },
  { ResourceId: 191,
    OfficeAddress:
     '20 Main Street\r\nRiverside\r\nUSA' },
  { ResourceId: 204,
    OfficeAddress:
     '20 Main Street\r\nRiverside\r\nUSA' }
]
```

I want to try and split the string into their own key/value pairs within the object, to this:

```
[ 
  { ResourceId: 2,
    address1: "20 Main Street",
    address2: "Riverside",
    address3: "USA"
    },
  { ResourceId: 191,
    address1: "20 Main Street",
    address2: "Riverside",
    address3: "USA"
    },
  { ResourceId: 204,
    address1: "20 Main Street",
    address2: "Riverside",
    address3: "USA"
    }
]
```

I can do something like this if it was **JUST** a normal string:

```
let output = addresses.split("\r").reduce(function(
        obj,
        str,
        index
      ) {
        let strParts = str.split(":");
        obj[strParts[0].replace(/\s+/g, "")] = strParts[1];
        return obj;
      },
      {});
```

Would any one know how I could loop through each object in the array and split the string into 3 address value/keys? A .map perhaps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think `map()` is the way to go since you want an array with an item for each input. Just make a new object with each iteration:

```js
var addresses = [ { ResourceId: 2,OfficeAddress:'20 Main Street\r\nRiverside\r\nUSA' },{ ResourceId: 191,OfficeAddress:'20 Main Street\r\nRiverside\r\nUSA' },{ ResourceId: 204,OfficeAddress:'20 Main Street\r\nRiverside\r\nUSA' }]

let newArray= addresses.map(({ResourceId,OfficeAddress }) => {
    let [address1, address2, address3] = OfficeAddress.split('\r\n')
    return {ResourceId, address1, address2, address3}
})
console.log(newArray)
```

You also might consider keeping the address in an array rather than individually named properties:

```js
var addresses = [ { ResourceId: 2,OfficeAddress:'20 Main Street\r\nRiverside\r\nUSA' },{ ResourceId: 191,OfficeAddress:'20 Main Street\r\nRiverside\r\nUSA' },{ ResourceId: 204,OfficeAddress:'20 Main Street\r\nRiverside\r\nUSA' }]

let newArray= addresses.map(({ResourceId,OfficeAddress }) => {
    let address = OfficeAddress.split('\r\n')
    return {ResourceId, address}
})
console.log(newArray)
```